# Java AES encryption: need files to decrypt properly in freely available decryptor tools

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes

I am using Java AES encryption to encrypt data which will be sent to a recipient. Each recipient will have their own key, which both they and I know.

The idea is that they can decrypt the data using freely available AES decryption tools.

Here is the my code:

```
public class AESencrypt {

    private static final String ALGO = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
    private static final byte[] keyValue = new byte[]{'T', 'h', 'e', 'B', 'e', 's', 't', 'S', 'e', 'c', 'r', 'e', 't', 'K', 'e', 'y'};
    private static byte[] iv = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

    public void String encryptToFile(String filename, String data) throws Exception {
        Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, "AES");
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ivspec);
        byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(data.getBytes());
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        fileOutputStream.write(encVal);
        fileOutputStream.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        encryptToFile("foo.aes", "hellothere");
    }
}
```

}

To verify this, I used an [Online AES Encryption / Decryption Tool](http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/) to decrypt some sample data (which worked fine!).

Now, I would like to use a free AES decryption tool so that the recipients can decrypt the data on their PC without using an online tool - and here is where the frustration starts.

I started installing and testing out various different AES decryptor tools: I carefully enter the key, choose the CBC algorithm, select my file and hit "decrypt", and yet none of the tools can decode my sample file `foo.aes` - they all fail with errors and in one case gave an empty file of zero bytes.

I tried this with at least 4 different AES encryptor/decryptor tools, and none of them worked to decrypt my file, which leads me to believe there might be a problem with my code.

- CriptAES
- AES Crypt
- Advanced AES Encryptor
- Cr!ptAES

If anyone can look over my code that would be greatly appreciated.

Alternatively there may be an AES decryptor tool that will work with the code above.

Comment: Don't use ECB, it's insecure

Comment: Ok, good point, so I also ran the same tests with CBC and an ivspec, and they still fail to decode in the decoder tools. Any ideas?

Comment: In 8 of 10 times I ran into issues with java encryption/decryption it was the padding. Do the tools use the correct padding?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Fildor: most of the tools have no option to specify the padding. I have tried both `NoPadding` (where my data is in 16 byte multiple total length) and `PKCS5Padding` in my code, hoping it will match (but something isn't right...)

Comment: Have you considered a standard such as PGP instead of creating your own from cryptographic primitives?

Comment: @ntoskrnl Unfortunately it's prescribed that I need to use AES encryption. If i understand correctly, PGP is something different to that.

Comment: @vikingsteve OpenPGP is more of data processing scheme, rather than encryption. As part of its operations OpenPGP can use AES for encryption of data. So your requirement is still met.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're facing is that while AES is a standard, it's just a *cryptographic primitive*, and you need a full *protocol*.

The protocol you've come up with works basically as follows:

- Pre-share the secret key somehow. The key is defined as 16 characters in the ASCII character set; a key derivation function should not be applied to it (pre-defined details).
- Encrypt the plaintext with AES, in CBC mode, with PKCS #5 padding (pre-defined details). Use a pre-defined IV.

As you see, there are several pre-defined details that both parties must be aware of for successful communication, and AES is only one of them. The tools you've tried apparently don't agree on all these details.

The solution is of course to use a standard protocol.

To choose an appropriate protocol, you must first determine *why* you need encryption, because encryption *per se* is not desirable goal. What are you trying to protect against?

In essence, encryption substitutes the confidentiality of a large amount of data with that of a small amount of data (the key). What happens if the user leaks the key by mistake? If you can securely send the key to a user, why can't you send the rest of the data through that channel too? (An article on the subject: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/27/keep-it-secret-keep-it-safe.aspx)

It is also important to realize that confidentiality is only one of many security properties. Your protocol fails to provide authenticity (guarantee that *you* created the message and that it has not been modified), because CBC is fairly malleable, and it may leak information about the plaintext, because you used a static IV.

As you can see, designing a secure protocol is far from easy. You must be aware of even the most minute details of your decisions. Even experts don't always get it right.

To avoid all the hassle, your best option is to use a well-established standard. Use [TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) for transferring data over a network connection, and [PGP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy) for encrypting data on disk. Both protocols are configurable for almost any use case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I want to press ahead with AES, so may I also ask if you are aware of any tools that can be configured to the protocol you describe? I was essentially using AES, in CBC mode, with PKCS #5 and an all-zeroes IV.

Comment: @vikingsteve I don't think there is a standard like that because, as said, it's not secure. Note that both TLS and PGP can be configured to use AES.

Answer (score 0):

You have 100 programmers => 100 different ideas.
What im trying to tell here is that maybe your code and lets say [CriptAES] are giving same output, but they [programmers of CriptAES for example] added some additional check/encryption/something so you cant decrypt it with any other tool. Maybe they are forcing users[people who use their tool] to use only that application [CriptAES] for encryption and decryption.
Its just idea, nothing more. Good luck.

Comment: I was thinking there should be some sort of standard here. If I were to say "here's a file, you decode it with AES encryption, CBC, PKCS5 padding", shouldn't that be enough for another developer to decode it? I really didn't want to get to the point that I had to ship my own decryptor tool, trivial as though that may be.

Answer (score 0):

Symmetric encryption (even with the same encryption algorithm) can be used in a number of ways and the product is then wrapped in another myriad of methods. Chances that two developers that don't follow some particular specification will produce the same output are close to zero.

I bet that those applications you've mentioned don't handle each other's output, i.e. they are not mutually compatible as well. If they are, then this means that they follow some standard or other document and then you need to implement the same standard.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I'll try those tools against each other and see how they fare. Interestingly, the online decryptor tool was really good - it accepted virtually all combinations of encrypted files that I generated (ECB vs CBC, padding vs no padding). Perhaps they just used similar java code to mine? I was hoping to find some sort of de-facto standard of AES configuration here, but didn't, at least so far.

Answer (score 0):

Well in the end I think I found a nice solution.

There is some Java source code at [AES Crypt](http://www.aescrypt.com/download/) and a corresponding lightweight utility program that you can share with users who need to decode the AES files you generate.

It seems like a good approach to me, unless anyone can say otherwise?